# How to draw lines between two datasets using VTK

Tags: vtk

I'm newer at vtk, so I hope that I'll find help here :)

I have two datasets of **vtkPolyData*** type:

Data_source and Data_target.

I calculated the correspondences between **Data_source** and **Data_target** and I have points **(x_source,y_source,z_source)** which match **(x_target,y_target,z_target)**. Now
my question is:

1-How to draw lines ,between to datasets, that rely **(x_source,y_source,z_source)** to **(x_target,y_target,z_target)**?

2-How to display them on a vtk window?

Greetings

W

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put all the points into one vtkPoints object, either

```
target_1, target_2, ..., target_N, source_1, source_2, source_N
```

or

```
target_1, source_1, target_2, source_2, target_N, source_N
```

(your choice).

You then have to create the lines between the corresponding points with:

```
 line->GetPointIds()->SetId(0,target_point);
 line->GetPointIds()->SetId(1,source_point);
```

according to the format you chose to store the points. A full example
of making and displaying lines here:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/ColoredLines